# How do I bring custom app (activity) atop of lock screen?

Tags: root-access, lock-screens, xposed-framework

Some applications (for example, MortPlayer Music and other music players, Camera app, etc.) can work atop of lock screen, without requiring to enter PIN.

How do I force existing app to show an activity even if screen is locked?

For example, I have some custom Calculator app and I think it is secure enough to be callable without unlocking the device. I can already start it without unlocking (method of doing so is out of scope for this question), but it's window gets visible only after closing lockscreen.

To do this I suppose one should "inject" `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission and `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` and `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` window flags.

Is this already done by somebody? Maybe there is some XPosed module for this?